# pid_to_list() changing value of pid?

Tags: erlang

I have code like:

```
PID = spawn_link(DistrNode, ......

io:format("~p debug1 ~n",[PID]),
io:format("~p debug2 ~n",[pid_to_list(PID)]),
```

and I get like:

> <10062.97.0> debug1
>
> "<9453.97.0>" debug2

I want grab PID as string but not change value like it did above- what is happening here? I looked convert pid to atom, but no function there.

I wanted to get "<10062.97.0>"

**EDIT it spawn_link() not spawn() this make difference?**

Answer (score 13):

What's happening is this: You're executing both calls to io:format() on node X, but PID is a process on node Y. The call to pid_to_list(PID) creates a string representing how PID is referenced from node X: "<9453.97.0>". This string is then sent to the I/O stream, which doesn't change the string any further.

However, when you call io:format("~p debug1 ~n",[PID]) on node X, the format string "~p debug1 ~n" and the arguments [PID] are sent as they are in the format I/O request on to the node Z which talks to the terminal, and PID is formatted on that node (also using pid_to_list(PID), generating <10062.97.0>. Note that only the first number differs; 10062 is the number that Z is using to refer to node Y, while X used 9453 to refer to node Y. 0 as the first number would mean it's a pid on the local node.